# JTree dynamically updating with arraylist changes

Tags: java, jtree

I looked for answer but wasn't able find anything to solve this. I have two array lists containing Strings that're changing dynamically after user click, and now creating JTree that will show elements from one list depends on some type in another list. I have a problem because I always add and delete something in my list and need JTree to show that changes. It will add all elements from List correctly till I expand, after that it's impossible to update content of JTree, at least for me. If I empty my list it will show like it's collapsed but all content is still showing like it's expanded even it gives in console that childcount is 0, and if I add something to my list it's going to add it but won't show it.
So basically the problem is to visually show changes of JTree.

```
public class JSelectedTree extends JPanel{
          private JTree selectionTree;
          private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
          public DefaultMutableTreeNode point;
          public DefaultMutableTreeNode polygon;
          public DefaultMutableTreeNode line;
          public JSelectedTree() {
            initGUI();
          }

          public void initGUI() {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
                point = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Point");
                polygon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Polygon");
                line = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Line");
                root.add(point);
                root.add(polygon);
                root.add(line);
                treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
                selectionTree = new JTree(root);
                selectionTree.setRootVisible(false);
                selectionTree.setShowsRootHandles(false);
                selectionTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                    TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(selectionTree);
                scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Selected"));
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              }
          public void resetTree(){
              if(!MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.isEmpty()){
                  polygon.removeAllChildren();
                  point.removeAllChildren();
                  line.removeAllChildren();
                  treeModel.reload();
                  int n = MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.size();
                  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                      if(MultiSelectTool.selectedCoords.get(i).contains("(((")){
                          DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.get(i));
                          treeModel.insertNodeInto(child, polygon, polygon.getChildCount());
                      }else if(MultiSelectTool.selectedCoords.get(i).contains("((")){
                          DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.get(i));
                          treeModel.insertNodeInto(child, line, line.getChildCount());
                      }else{
                          DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.get(i));
                          treeModel.insertNodeInto(child, point, point.getChildCount());
                      }
                  }
              }else{
                  polygon.removeAllChildren();
                  point.removeAllChildren();
                  line.removeAllChildren();
                  treeModel.reload();
              }
          }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to spend a good amount of time to read about the **model** part here. The **model** connects the data and the visual view. So, in theory, you only need to hook up things correctly to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by taking some parts from DynamicTreeDemo and here is code if somebody need something like this

```
public class JSelectedTree extends JPanel{
          static JButton addButton; 
          public static DynamicTree treePanel;
          public DefaultMutableTreeNode point;
          public DefaultMutableTreeNode polygon;
          public DefaultMutableTreeNode line;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode p1, p2, p3;
          public JSelectedTree() {

                treePanel = new DynamicTree();
                populateTree(treePanel);
                addButton = new JButton("Add");
                addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                          if(!MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.isEmpty()){
                              treePanel.clear();
                              populateTree(treePanel);
                              int n = MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.size();
                              for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                                  if(MultiSelectTool.selectedCoords.get(i).contains("(((")){

                                      String child = new String(MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.get(i));
                                      treePanel.addObject(p1,child, true);
                                  }else if(MultiSelectTool.selectedCoords.get(i).contains("((")){
                                      String child = new String(MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.get(i));
                                      treePanel.addObject(p2,child, true);
                                  }else{
                                      String child = new String(MultiSelectTool.selectedObject.get(i));
                                      treePanel.addObject(p3,child, true);
                                  }
                              }
                          }else{
                                treePanel.clear();
                                  populateTree(treePanel);
                            }
                    }
                });
                treePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                add(treePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                treePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Selected"));
          }

          public void populateTree(DynamicTree treePanel) {
                String p1Name = new String("Polygon");
                String p2Name = new String("Point");
                String p3Name = new String("Line");



                p1 = treePanel.addObject(null, p1Name, true);
                p2 = treePanel.addObject(null, p2Name, true);
                p3 = treePanel.addObject(null, p3Name, true);

              }
}
          class DynamicTree extends JPanel {
              protected DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
              protected DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
              protected JTree tree;
              private Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

              public DynamicTree() {
                super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

                rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node");
                treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);

                tree = new JTree(treeModel);
                tree.setEditable(true);
                tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                    TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
                tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
                add(scrollPane);
              }

              /** Remove all nodes except the root node. */
              public void clear() {
                rootNode.removeAllChildren();
                treeModel.reload();
              }

              /** Remove the currently selected node. */
              public void removeCurrentNode() {
                TreePath currentSelection = tree.getSelectionPath();
                if (currentSelection != null) {
                  DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (currentSelection
                      .getLastPathComponent());
                  MutableTreeNode parent = (MutableTreeNode) (currentNode.getParent());
                  if (parent != null) {
                    treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);
                    return;
                  }
                }

                // Either there was no selection, or the root was selected.
                toolkit.beep();
              }

              public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent,
                  Object child) {
                return addObject(parent, child, false);
              }

              public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent,
                  Object child, boolean shouldBeVisible) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child);

                if (parent == null) {
                  parent = rootNode;
                }

                // It is key to invoke this on the TreeModel, and NOT DefaultMutableTreeNode
                treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());

                // Make sure the user can see the lovely new node.
                if (shouldBeVisible) {
                  tree.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(childNode.getPath()));
                }
                return childNode;
              }

              class MyTreeModelListener implements TreeModelListener {
                public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
                  DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
                  node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());

                  /*
                   * If the event lists children, then the changed node is the child of the
                   * node we've already gotten. Otherwise, the changed node and the
                   * specified node are the same.
                   */

                  int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
                  node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));

                  System.out.println("The user has finished editing the node.");
                  System.out.println("New value: " + node.getUserObject());
                }

                public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
                }

                public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e) {
                }

                public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you please also share the MultiSelectTool class? Or even better, if you have this code publicly available somewhere, please share, I'm currently on the look for a similar problem I'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339957/simple-dynamic-jtree-based-s3-bucket-object-chooser-example

Comment: in MultiSelectTool after adding elements to ArrayList selectedObject, I call JSelectedTree.addButton.doClick(); which then update the tree.
It is probably better to try creating listeners on the list for updates of a tree, but this was the first thing that came up to my mind when I was writing this

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an MVC pattern so you can update the view:)