# Simple dynamic JTree-based S3 bucket/object chooser example

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tree, aws-sdk

Before writing my own custom implementation, I have been googling for a complete example of a simple tree-like JTree/JDialog that allows me to **dynamically load and expand the contents of a S3 bucket** or sub-S3-object-keys.

In other words, **I don't want to recursively prefetch all the objects from different buckets beforehand and populate a JTree**. The reason is that there are too many (sub-)objects and keys to have a smooth UX experience, in the order of millions/billions of objects spread in different S3 buckets that don't need to be opened by the user during a session.

Put simply, **the ideal solution would be like a regular filesystem `FileChooser` but for Amazon S3 buckets**. For more context, [here is the closest I've got to finding what I need](https://github.com/FlowJo-LLC/FlowJo-AWS-S3-Plugin/blob/master/AWSS3Plugin/awss3plugin/AWSS3GUI.java#L735).

But unfortunately it doesn't implement the **on-expanding of subtrees usecase**. On the other hand, [this other SO example is a close match, but very incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967989/jtree-dynamically-updating-with-arraylist-changes/37968170)... I suspect that better snippets should be available, perhaps it's just my google-fu failing me on this one?

I am aware that [buckets/keys are not filesystems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561432/amazon-s3-listing-directories), but for my usecase and purposes, that's what I need.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we managed to solve this problem, for more pointers see the following github repo for a barebones example not integrating AWS S3 buckets:

https://github.com/reisingerf/SwingDynamicTree

and the final integration with S3 browser:

https://github.com/igvteam/igv/pull/620

Hope that helps somebody wondering the same :)